# Why I can't see the CNAME record of a specific domain?

Tags: cname, nslookup, dig

why when I want to see which CNAMES has a specific domain I can't see them using dig/nslookup?
`nslookup -type=any google.com`

Are CNAMES protected against public petitions?
Output from command:

```
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
Server:     8.8.4.4
Address:    8.8.4.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.185.206
google.com  has AAAA address 2a00:1450:4001:812::200e
google.com  mail exchanger = 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com  text = "google-site-verification=wD8N7i1JTNTkezJ49swvWW48f8_9xveREV4oB-0Hf5o"
google.com  nameserver = ns2.google.com.
google.com  mail exchanger = 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com  nameserver = ns3.google.com.
google.com  text = "MS=E4A68B9AB2BB9670BCE15412F62916164C0B20BB"
google.com  rdata_257 = 0 issue "pki.goog"
google.com  text = "globalsign-smime-dv=CDYX+XFHUw2wml6/Gb8+59BsH31KzUr6c1l2BPvqKX8="
google.com  nameserver = ns1.google.com.
google.com  text = "facebook-domain-verification=22rm551cu4k0ab0bxsw536tlds4h95"
google.com  mail exchanger = 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com  text = "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
google.com  text = "apple-domain-verification=30afIBcvSuDV2PLX"
google.com  text = "docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e"
google.com  mail exchanger = 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com  text = "google-site-verification=TV9-DBe4R80X4v0M4U_bd_J9cpOJM0nikft0jAgjmsQ"
google.com  nameserver = ns4.google.com.
google.com  mail exchanger = 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com
    origin = ns1.google.com
    mail addr = dns-admin.google.com
    serial = 384422044
    refresh = 900
    retry = 900
    expire = 1800
    minimum = 60
google.com  text = "docusign=1b0a6754-49b1-4db5-8540-d2c12664b289"

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Answer (score -2):

CNAME records are public, you should be able to see them. If you're not seeing them it will most likely be the case that the domain has no CNAME records at all.

Try a couple different domains, especially subdomains as they usually contain CNAME records. e.g.

```
~ → nslookup -type=CNAME www.pinterest.com

Server:     2001:558:feed::1
Address:    2001:558:feed::1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.pinterest.com   canonical name = www-pinterest-com.gslb.pinterest.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Comment: Wouldn't be asking the question if it was that simple ;-)